# jsonp for xml-cross domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, jakarta-ee, jsonp

I am trying to find a way for xml cross-domain. After googling I found that might be done by jsonp, but I did not get very well the way how it works also after seeing [jsonp with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681466/jsonp-with-jquery) and [Basic how-to for cross domain jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463256/basic-how-to-for-cross-domain-jsonp).

I have a pice of html code like following:

```
<form id="f" name="f" method="POST" action="index.php">
<input type="text" id="t" name="t">
</form>
```

and in javascript part:

```
if( typeof (xmlhttp)=="object")
    {
        xmlhttp["open"]("GET",pURL,true);
    }
}
```

where `pURL = index.php?p1="x"&p2="y"`

I tried something but it does not work,so I am wondering how I can change the following code to make it correct?

```
<script>
$.getJSON("http://domainXYZ.com.indexPHP?jsoncallback=?",
  {
    t: "inputValue"
  },
  function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(data){
      alert(data);
    });
  });</script>
```

Any Idea will be appreciated.

Comment: First question: Does the server respond with JSONP?  There will be no advantage to getting your client-side right if the server does not supply JSONP responses.  You should be able to test by loading the url into a browser window and seeing if you get a response that is designed to use your callback function.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried following url in the browser: http://www.domainXYZ.com/abc.aspx?Code=XYZjsoncallback=? and I see the page, does it mean that the server respond with JSONP?

Comment: A JSONP response will look like `yourCallbackName({"some": "json"});` instead of simply `{"some": "json"}`.  `yourCallbackName` would replace the `?` in the url.

Comment: I did not get your point, for example for following url I just see the script: http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?

Comment: As far as I can tell, that URL supplies an RSS feed, no JSON at all.  You're not going to parse XML with a JSON parser.

Comment: Look at the difference between [a plain json](http://api.wikilocation.org/articles?lat=51.500688&lng=-0.124411&limit=1) and [a jsonp](http://api.wikilocation.org/articles?lat=51.500688&lng=-0.124411&limit=1&jsonp=handleArticles) request to the wikilocation api.