# jQuery Parse JSON URL

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to get the JSON data from a URL that outputs the following JSON data:

```
[
 {
    "belief_desc":"Jesus Died For Your Sins",
    "0":"Jesus Died For Your Sins"
 },
 {
    "belief_desc":"People Are Sinful",
    "0":"People Are Sinful"
 },
 {
    "belief_desc":"God Loves You",
    "0":"God Loves You"
 },
 {
    "belief_desc":"We Must Receive Christ",
    "0":"We Must Receive Christ"
 }
]
```

(Note: it is only formatted in this question for easier reading.)

Now I am trying to parse through it using this simple jQuery script:

```
<script>
    var url = "http://mySite.com/data.json";
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
        alert(data);
        });
</script>
```

I am getting no data from the URL as the alert will not show. Any ideas on why this is not working?

Comment: Can you use Firebug and see what is coming back in the console? Just to be super sure? Is your page located on bsucru.comoj.com? If not, you can't do JSON due to security reasons.

Comment: Is your page on `bsucru.comoj.com` somewhere or another domain?

Comment: The page I am running the script is not on that domain. I am just using a local page to try and get that data.

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: you are not allowed to make cross domain ajax requests. if you are using chrome, start it with `--disable-web-security` option. This will let you make cross domain requests.

Comment: Check this: https://jsonp.nodejitsu.com/ and http://enable-cors.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cross domain you can't do simple JSON.

[Basic how-to for cross domain jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463256/basic-how-to-for-cross-domain-jsonp)

Read up on cross domain requests.

Comment: I am still not having any luck. I'm using the example from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681466/jsonp-with-jquery and simply replacing the URL. Could it have to do with how I encode the JSON url? I am using json_encode with PHP on an array from a MySQL database.

Comment: It's most likely something server side, (the side which is generating the JSON data). I am not familiar with cross-domain JSON, I just know there are some extra hoops to jump through to get it to work.