# Success callback not working in $.getJSON

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, cross-domain

I have a cross domain webservice which i want to call, however when i try to call it, i get a proper response in json (checked in firebug) but success callback never fires, instead it executes the error callback.

Here is my javascript code.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON("http://[external domain]/Service.asmx/SendMail?callback=?", { 'body': txtEmail.value }, function (data) {
                alert("SUCCESS");
            })
            .error(function (data) { alert("ERROR: " + data.responseText); })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my webservice code.

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="Service" %>
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[ScriptService]

public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void SendMail(string body)
    {
        Context.Response.Clear();
        Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        try
        {
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress("[senders mail]");
            message.To.Add("[recepient mail]");
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.Priority = MailPriority.High;
            message.Subject = "[subject]";
            message.Body = body;

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("[username]", "[password]");
            client.Send(message);



            string str = "{\"value\" : \"sent\"}";
            // also tried with JavascriptSerializer like in catch block, that too not working.
            Context.Response.Flush(); 
            Context.Response.Write(str);


        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            string str = js.Serialize(ex.Message);
            Context.Response.Flush();
            Context.Response.Write(str);
        }

    }    
}
```

Below is the response traced in firebug.
[image]

can anyone tell me what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably as your web service is in external domain, it is a crossdomain issue.
You have to use **jsonp** for this.

You can take a look here - [Basic how-to for cross domain jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463256/basic-how-to-for-cross-domain-jsonp)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i have already used ?callback=? as it is a cross-domain, in this case it should be working, am i missing anything else.

Comment: You need to set the JSONPBehavior  at the service level. Check out http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/DataServicesJSONP