# How to add SoundCloud files to jPlayer?

Tags: html, soundcloud, jplayer, audio-player

Right now I have a website that uses jPlayer to stream mp3s on. I also want to be able to add the functionality of letting SoundCloud stream directly on the player.

I know this is possible, because one of my favorite music blogs [hillydilly](http://www.hillydilly.com/) does this. From looking at their code, I see their setup for their jPlayer has a few extra arguments, namely sc and sclink.

```
$(".play-music").each(function(){
        myPlaylist.add({
         title: $(this).attr('data-title'),
         artist: $(this).attr('data-artist'),
         mp3: $(this).attr('data-mp3'),
         url: $(this).attr('data-url'),
         sc: $(this).attr('data-sc'),
         sclink: $(this).attr('data-sclink')         
        });
});
```

I tried looking through the rest of their code, but can't figure out how or where they implement sc and sclink. Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at their playlist they're linking to Soundcloud for the mp3 property of the track:

```
myPlaylist.setPlaylist([

{
        title:"Close Enough ft. Noosa",
    artist:"Ghost Beach",
    mp3:"http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/79031167/stream?client_id=db10c5086fe237d1718f7a5184f33b51",
    url:"http://hillydilly.com/2012/12/top-20-songs/",
    sc:"true"
    },
    {
        title:"Always",
    artist:"Jahan Lennon",
    mp3:"http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/80961874/stream?client_id=db10c5086fe237d1718f7a5184f33b51",
    url:"http://hillydilly.com/2012/12/top-20-songs/",
    sc:"true"
    }
```

HTML5 'streams' are really just MP3s you currently can't protect them like you can with Flash, Silverlight, Quicktime etc. If you open one of those links directly (like http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/79031167/stream?client_id=db10c5086fe237d1718f7a5184f33b51) it'll download the MP3. So I'm guessing it you set it up the same way it should just work.

If you open up Chrome and its Network inspector (in dev tools: View > Developer > Developer Tools, then click Network) and click next on Hilly's player you can see the track loading in the background.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Actually kreek's answer is only half the story.

If you want to stream soundcloud songs, you first of all need to register your website on the developer page [developers.soundcloud.com](http://developers.soundcloud.com).

Then use their [super cool API](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks) with **your own** key. You can either load the json into your php and generate links there or you load the information with jquery $.getJSON.

When streaming sounds from soundcloud you also want to be sure to properly attribute. The people from soundcloud are very generous to let us use their database like that.

//sorry for the bad links (no credits)

[How do I use external JSON...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344609/how-do-i-use-external-json)

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/buttons-logos