# HOW TO PHP JSON DATA convert PHP Treeview

Tags: php, json

Hi Guys I have a JSON data I need to convert this data Treeview a json data url: http://torrent2dl.ml/json.php
recovered state = http://torrent2dl.ml/json.php?tree

I tried to do http://torrent2dl.ml/hedef.php
 how to convert this data a php function or code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `json_decode()` :

```
<?php
$url = 'http://torrent2dl.ml/json.php';
$JSON = file_get_contents($url);

// echo the JSON (you can echo this to JavaScript to use it there)
echo $JSON;

// You can decode it to process it in PHP
$data = json_decode($JSON);
var_dump($data);
?>
```

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8344667/4652564

Answer (score 1):

`json_decode($jsonObject, true);`