# jQuery ajax call to domain that redirects to another domain (isn't followed)

Tags: ajax, jquery, cross-domain

This is sort of a cross-domain issue, but the problem is the browser (Chrome) doesn't seem to follow the redirect. Instead, nothing is returned to the jQuery ajax call, and I get an error.

I'm trying to use `jQuery.ajax`, but the URL that I'm using redirects to another domain. When this happens, I get an error. Is there anything special that needs to be done so the browser will follow the redirect?

I already added `access-control-allow-origin: *` to the header of the second domain that is being redirected to.

Comment: Can you add your code and the error you see?

Comment: You're not allowed to fetch data from other domains in your ajax.

Answer (score 1):

An HTTP redirect page is treated as any other HTTP page in that it also needs the access control headers. If your redirect page does not have them, the browser will never get around to checking if the page being redirected to has the proper permissions.

Along with the `Location` header on the redirect page, also add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and its related constituents (i.e. `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` etc.)

Comment: there is a lot of theory in your answer.. a couple of lines of code to illustrate what you're saying won't hurt

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get a cross-domain ajax call is to use jsonp.

In jQuery, set your `.ajax()` dataType to 'jsonp'. See here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

It still may not work, if the server being redirected to is not capable of a jsonp response. The difference between a json response and a jsonp response is that a json response is a pure json string, while a jsonp response is the code that calls a function passing in a json string.

A not-too-shabby tutorial: http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/

A good discussion: [Can anyone explain what JSONP is, in layman terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839966/can-any-one-explain-me-what-is-jsonp-in-layman-terms)

Comment: cross domain ajax call is possible with Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) and author worked with this technology ( as he mentioned "access-control-allow-origin: *"  header. )

Comment: @vadimk, Perhaps you can supply an answer involving this approach then. But it seems from the post that the problem is on the client-side. The `access-control-allow-origin` approach with CORS is on the server side. Even if the server allows it, the client wasn't allowing it. Thus JSONP.

Comment: Jonathan, check out my answer. The solution involves making sure the redirect page has the proper response headers.