# how to execute external script with jquery

Tags: getscript

i want to execute an advertisement script after the page has been loaded. 
i know that i have to use something like this:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
$.getScript('http://anetwork.ir/showad/?adwidth=468&adheight=60&aduser=1341223032', function() {
    // callback function
    alert('external script loaded!');
  });
});
```

but it's not working, although the alert loads. also there is no problem with

```
$(window).bind("load", function()
```

the problem must be from $.getScript .
i also must add that the external script outputs something like this:

```
document.write('<iframe scrolling="no" width="468" height="60" frameborder="0" src="http://anetwork.ir/showad/c.php?adwidth=468&adheight=60&aduser=1341223032">
```

');

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
$(window).load(function() {
   // this will be executed when the page has finished loading
}
```

If there is a problem with the script and not the load function, keep reading.

`$.getScript` is a shortcut for an ajax call. You can find more on that in the documentation on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/. Because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) it is not possible to load the script. You will have to use `JSONP` in order to load the script from a different domain. You can find more details on this in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839966/can-anyone-explain-what-jsonp-is-in-layman-terms/3840118#3840118).

Comment: but my problem is with $.getScript, the load event is working.