# Convert jsonp to json

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, jsonp

Here is my code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://example.com?keyword=r&callback=jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) {
        var errorMessage = exception || xhr.statusText;
        alert("Excep:: " + exception + "Status:: " + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
```

OK so the above code works fine and i'm getting a data as jsonp.Now i cant figure out how to convert jsonp to json.

Comment: There's no such thing as "json object". JSON is a cross-platform serialized data in the form of a string. It is also different than JSONP. And as @FelixKling said, jQuery will automatically parse it into an object if you did everything correctly.

Comment: You shouldn't add `&callback=jsonp` to the URL, jQuery will take care of that. Also, if everything works fine, `data` should already be the JS object you need. So, what exactly is your problem? What is `data`?

Comment: Read about JSONP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839966/can-anyone-explain-what-jsonp-is-in-layman-terms

Comment: Make sure your server is converting your JSON to a JSONP when it's returning the request.  It needs to be wrapped in a function call.

Comment: @FelixKling well actually if i dont add a callback to the url it isn't working dats y i appended &callback=jsonp .Its an external url and dats how it will work

Comment: *"the url it isn't working"* means what exactly? If you add `jsonp: 'jsonp'` as option for `$.ajax`, does it "work" then? We still don't know what the problem with your code is...

Comment: What does your alert give you *exactly*.

Comment: it gives [object object] as u said

Comment: In that case, if your json contains a key `"foo"` with a value `"bar"`, `alert(data.foo)` should give you `bar`.

Comment: @jade: Then everything is working fine. You get the response, `data` is an object (or array) and you can access it like any other object/array. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value. Don't use `alert` for inspecting variables, use `console.log`.

Answer (score 4):

This article may give you some additional guidance: [Basic example of using .ajax() with JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp)

Can you provide us with an example of the data structure returned by the request?

In your particular circumstance, you could probably do something similar to the following. Let me know how this turns out:

```
// Create the function the JSON data will be passed to.
function myfunc(json) {
  alert(json);
}

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://example.com?keyword=r&callback=jsonp",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonpCallback: 'myfunc', // the function to call
  jsonp: 'callback', // name of the var specifying the callback in the request
  error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) {
    var errorMessage = exception || xhr.statusText;
    alert("Excep:: " + exception + "Status:: " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```

Comment: so should i remove success from ajax

Comment: Actually, JSONP is not JSON at all, it's just JavaScript code.

Comment: There's no reason to eval in this case... you could simply do `<script src="http://example.com?keyword=r&callback=jsonp"></script>` after defining that function globally. jquery also offers ways of making a same-domain jsonp request with a specific jsonp callback if you must use jQuery to do the request.

Comment: No reason to feel offended or be offensive... just trying to clarify things. Also I'm not sure if `eval(data)` would even work here. I don't think jQuery passes the source of the script to the success callback, because of the way JSONP works (I don't think it's even possible to get the source).

Comment: @JoshuaBurns eval is not working....its not getting to the jsonp call back function

Comment: jQuery is actually smart enough to detect the `callback=jsonp` create inside the URL, create a function with such a name and so that it is called from the script and pass the result to the success callback. See: http://jsfiddle.net/Q42Mb/1/. `eval` doesn't do anything in this case.

Comment: yup you're right, pretty nifty :D i've updated the code with a better use.

Answer (score 2):

> Now i cant figure out how to convert jsonp to json.

That's pointless. What you want is a plain javascript object to work with, and you already have that (`data`).

---

**JSONP** is a script file where a function is called with an object literal. The literal looks like *JSON*, and the function (whose name is dynamically generated) is the *padding*.

**JSON** is a file/string containing data in [*JavaScript Object Notation*](http://json.org/), a common serialisation format.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an alert from `alert(data)`, it's already being converted. You should be getting `[object Object]` which should tell you that you have a JavaScript object. Now you can access it's properties just like any other JavaScript object.

```
alert(data.foo);
```

It may also be an array depending on the json being returned.

Answer (score 0):

you need a function:

```
function jsonp(data){
    // do stuff with data here
}
```

the function is called automatically when the data is returned/