# Execute javascript directly in the HTTP response

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, http

Some years ago I wrote a system where I'm pretty sure that I was able to execute javascript directly from the HTTP response.

What I did was to set the `Content-Type`to `application/javascript` and then simply include the script in the response body.

Now I'm trying to do the same thing with just a simple alert:  `alert('Hello world');` as the HTTP response body. But the browser doesn't execute the script but just treats it as text.

Am I doing something wrong, or have it never been possible? (It's not an ajax request).

Comment: The browser expects HTML... Have you tried encapsulating the script in minimal HTML, including a <body onLoad="..."> ?

Comment: How are you initiating the request?

Comment: @RoyDictus: the `Content-Type` controls what the browser expects.

Comment: @RichieHindle: I've tried both with GET and POST.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how JSONP works. Simply add a `<script />` tag, whose `src` is set to the remote script your want to execute, and you'll be good to go.

In your application:

```
var tag = document.createElement("script");

tag.src = "/your-remote-page/";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag);
```

/your-remote-page:

```
alert("Hi");
```

For more info on JSONP, see [Can anyone explain what JSONP is, in layman terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839966/can-anyone-explain-what-jsonp-is-in-layman-terms/3840118#3840118)

If you have a response which *conditionally* returns either a file or a JavaScript response, then I'm not aware of a way you can *either* let the user download the file, *or* execute the JavaScript. The methods used to handle those responses are mutually exclusive. *Either* you inject a `<script />` tag (for JavaScript), or submit a form/ anchor (file download).

Comment: Not possible. The response is conditinal depending on the incoming data. It can either be a file or a javascript.

Comment: @jgauffin: The response can either be a file or a JavaScript? That doesn't sound very consistent...

Comment: @Cerbrus: It's not my system. I'm just helping. There is a large calculation going on where some cases required additional verification from the user. They do not want to redo everything as the most common case generates the PDF.

Comment: @jgauffin: _"It's not my system"_: Yea, that explains that :-)

Comment: @jgauffin: If my answer isn't possible, then I'm AFAIK, you're out of options.

Comment: @Matt: That will blank the page. That's why I wanted to use `content-type: application/javascript` as it should automatically execute everything on the current page. Remember that it's a regular request and not ajax. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @jgauffin: That's why I rolled back the edit. I forgot it's not an AJAX request :(. Setting the `Content-Type` to JavaScript isn't enough. The request *has* to be loaded via a `<script />` tag for that to work.

Comment: guess I remember incorrectly then :( Thanks for the clarification