# Jquery callback - Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, callback

I think the below problem is scope related but I'm not very good with jQuery plugin pattern, how can I solve it ?

**Details**
I'm trying to fix [an issue](https://github.com/EvanPalmer/TpbImdbSearch/issues/4) (Cross Domain) with this [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tpb-imdb-pirate-bay-searc/balopjhbkeaphbdgegdgeckdjhoaencd?hl=en)

I think I found a solution ( using `anyorigin.com` ) but I got an new  problem with the `$.getJSON`:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery19109374020271279013_1462700430014 is not defined:

?url=https%3A//thepiratebay.cr/search/I%20Will%20Survive%201999/0/7/0&callback=jQuery19109374020271…:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery19109374020271279013_1462700430016 is not defined(anonymous function) @ ?url=https%3A//thepiratebay.cr/search/I%20Will%20Survive%201999/0/7/0&callback=jQuery19109374020271…:1
```

Here the code involved `doSearch()` is where I go the issue:

```
    (function($) {
        $.fn.extend({
            tpbSearch : function(options){
                var defaults = { searchTerm: ''};
                var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
                return this.each(function(){
                    doSearch($(this), options.searchTerm);
                })
            }
        });

        // private functions
        // ....

        function buildSearchUrl(searchTerm)
        {
            var searchPart = 'https://thepiratebay.cr/search/' + encodeURIComponent(searchTerm) + '/0/7/0';
            var searchUrl = 'http://anyorigin.com/get?url=' +  escape(searchPart) + '&callback=?';

            return searchUrl;
        }
        // function where the issue happens.
       function doSearch(container, searchTerm){
            // here we should iterate over the container selector, because it's possible multiple items will be selected.
            var sanitizedSearchTerm = sanitizeSearchTerm(searchTerm);

            // set the default logo
            var loadingImageUrl = chrome.extension.getURL('images/ajax-loader.gif');
            var logo = $('<img id="tpb-logo">')
                        .attr('src', loadingImageUrl)
                        .css('width', '25px')
                        .css('height', '25px');
            container.children().remove();
            container.append(logo);

            var searchUrl = buildSearchUrl(sanitizedSearchTerm);

            $.getJSON(searchUrl, function(data){
                alert('aa');
            });
        }
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the right way to do it from a Chrome extension anyway.

If you run into cross-origin problems, you need to define host permissions for that origin. Then Chrome will ignore CORS. See [Requesting cross-origin permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#requesting-permission) in Google documentation.

---

For completeness, though I discourage you from fixing this:

Your error here is treating [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839966/can-anyone-explain-what-jsonp-is-in-layman-terms) in a content script. JSONP works by inserting a `<script>` element, but that executes in page's context while the callback is in a [separate content script context](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment). This gives the error of being unable to find the callback function.

Using JSONP is really awkward in content scripts as a result and if ABSOLUTELY needed should be delegated to the background page (with [appropriate CSP considerations](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-remote-script)).

Comment: I'm not sure if you are right about the JSON part ( the same command, on the same page with in js console works ... ) anyway you are absolutely right about the CORS and Chrome ext. that works like a charm. Thx

Comment: Ah, that code is from a content script. Then the problem is isolated world. I updated the answer to be correct.