# Using the $.getJSON method bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to use $.getJSON for a function, and i have 2 alerts: inside1 and inside x2. When i run the site, only the first alert is processed, and the code never actually reaches the second alert. What can i do to make the code process the function? I would really appreciate help with my code.

```
function get_photos(searchtag){

    var apikey = '#######################';

    alert('inside1');

    $.getJSON('api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=' + apikey + '&tags=' + searchtag + '&perpage=3&format=json', function (data) {
        alert('inside x2');
});
```

Here is what the url returns (which i have double checked to be the correct URL several times):

```
jsonFlickrApi({
        "photos": "page": 1,
        "pages": 103436,
        "perpage": 3,
        "total": "310306",
        "photo": [{
            "id": "28437400284",
            "owner": "20925280@N00",
            "secret": "711b34701c",
            "server": "8708",
            "farm": 9,
            "title": "20160810-DSC_0158",
            "ispublic": 1,
            "isfriend": 0,
            "isfamily": 0
        }, {
            "id": "29058577365",
            "owner": "20925280@N00",
            "secret": "bd73425d36",
            "server": "8319",
            "farm": 9,
            "title": "20160810-DSC_0159",
            "ispublic": 1,
            "isfriend": 0,
            "isfamily": 0
        }, {
            "id": "28437396394",
            "owner": "20925280@N00",
            "secret": "7de3504657",
            "server": "8877",
            "farm": 9,
            "title": "Sailing",
            "ispublic": 1,
            "isfriend": 0,
            "isfamily": 0
        }]
    }, "stat": "ok"
    })
```

Comment: The response shown isn't JSON, it's JSON-P. If you check the browser console you should see an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @nnnnnn mentioned in the comments, you can't use JSON to get cross-domain data with HTTP requests in javascript. You need to use JSONP. You need to replace `$.getJSON(...)` with:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=' + apikey + '&tags=' + searchtag + '&perpage=3&format=json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        alert('inside x2');
        // You can see the response.
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much =D
If you don't mind, how can i tell the difference between JSON and JSONP?

Comment: @Stanky happy to help :) The answer to this question offers some good insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839966/can-anyone-explain-what-jsonp-is-in-layman-terms