# JSONP call with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsonp

I am following the logic [outlined in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839966/can-anyone-explain-what-jsonp-is-in-layman-terms).

The code works when I run this in regular JavaScript. However, when placed in React, it doesn't.

```
stonktank:function myRun(json){
     document.getElementById('sting').innerHTML = json.Symbol;    

     var stockscript = document.createElement('script');
     stockscript.src = 'http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp?symbol=AAPL&callback=myRun';
     document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(stockscript);    
},
```

The error I get is `myRun` is not defined.

Comment: "myRun is not defined" means you need a global `myRun` function that can be called back. Shouldn't relate to React, but maybe strict mode? How are you defining `myRun`? You'd need it no matter what libraries you're using.