# Instagram API SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: fetch, instagram-api

I have a site that needs to load some images from Instagram. I'm using Fetch to make the request to Instagram's API. The request is successful but I get this error when processing the request, `error SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`.

The request comes back as 200 and with valid JSON. It seems like once the Fetch response completes the response is empty thus resulting in the SyntaxError.

http://jsbin.com/kohito/edit?html,js,console

I removed my access token from the example.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to go with [jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839966/can-anyone-explain-what-jsonp-is-in-layman-terms) to consume the Instagram API using the [Client-Side (Implicit) Authentication](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) method. You can bring in [fetch-jsonp](https://github.com/camsong/fetch-jsonp) to make a "fetch-like" request.

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch-jsonp/1.1.0/fetch-jsonp.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  fetchJsonp('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?' + window.location.hash.split('#')[1], {
    method: 'GET',
  }).then(response => {
    response.json().then((json) => {
      console.log(json);
    });
  });
  </script>
```