# Why webpack use jsonp to get chunk script

Tags: webpack, jsonp

I don't think there's a CORS issue.

Why webpack use jsonp to get chunk script?

This is generated webpackBootstrap.

```js
/******/    // install a JSONP callback for chunk loading
/******/    var parentJsonpFunction = window["webpackJsonp"];
/******/    window["webpackJsonp"] = function webpackJsonpCallback(chunkIds, moreModules) {
/******/        // add "moreModules" to the modules object,
/******/        // then flag all "chunkIds" as loaded and fire callback
/******/        var moduleId, chunkId, i = 0, callbacks = [];
/******/        for(;i < chunkIds.length; i++) {
/******/            chunkId = chunkIds[i];
/******/            if(installedChunks[chunkId])
/******/                callbacks.push.apply(callbacks, installedChunks[chunkId]);
/******/            installedChunks[chunkId] = 0;
/******/        }
/******/        for(moduleId in moreModules) {
/******/            modules[moduleId] = moreModules[moduleId];
/******/        }
/******/        if(parentJsonpFunction) parentJsonpFunction(chunkIds, moreModules);
/******/        while(callbacks.length)
/******/            callbacks.shift().call(null, __webpack_require__);
/******/    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thought here is,

Whether webpack uses `JSON` or `JSONP`, it has to append the loaded chunk file into the document.

So webpack team might have though that instead of getting the script file first (`JSON`) and then appending with the document, append the script tag first (`JSONP`) and then let the script tag load the file.

Nice explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3840118/744534) on JSON and JSONP

Comment: whaaaaaaaaaaaat

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow/understand the original answer. Here's my crack at it,

A JSONP is a **javascript file** which just contains a function wrapping JSON data. The name of that function can typically be named dynamically to whatever the requester wants it to be called,

```js
// client code
function myCallback(data) { console.log(data); }

var jsonp = document.createElement("script");
jsonp.src = '/jsonp_server_route?callback=myCallback';
document.head.appendChild(jsonp);
```

```js
// '/jsonp_server_route?callback=myCallback' served content
myCallback( { "foo": 1 } );
```

If you have a function named `myCallback` defined, `myCallback` will get called, and boom! You got your data... Like magic. But, it's actually just a clever javascript hack/technique (IMO of course).

**Okay... How does this apply to Webpack chunk scripts?**

Well, obviously chunk scripts are not necessarily JSON. They'll probably be script files most of the time. But, I think the same JSONP principle of wrapping **something** (could be JSON, a script, a string, etc) in a function can still apply.

Webpack probably wraps chunk scripts in a function. Hence, they use the verbiage 'JSONP'.

That's it. :)

PS
Since Webpack controls naming in all of the output files, the name for the JSONP callback function would already be known across files at build-time. So, the JSONP callback function name wouldn't need to be set dynamically (at run-time).