# How to read data returned from JSNOP jQuery.ajax all

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have set very simple php page which return rows feteched from mysql. On localhost my jquery page is

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "http://abcd.com/cccbsapp/test.php",

        // Tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
        dataType: "jsonp",

        complete:function(data){
            console.log(data)
        }           
    })
```

but console.log shows

[image]

I am not been able to get the actual JSON array returned by my php page. But console/network tab shows the returned data.
[image]

So I know that data is returning from remote server, but how can I get it in $.ajax.

When I use dataType:"JSON", it give CORS error, so I am using JSNOP. I am not very experienced with that.

Comment: A little Google will take one far - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839966/can-anyone-explain-what-jsonp-is-in-layman-terms 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

HNY!

Comment: @Rafael, I already tried these links, the problem is, when I give dataType: 'jsonp', the success event never get fired. Any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, that in order to use `JSONP`, the server needs to reply in a special way, not just print the data in JSON format.

When using `jsonp`, jQuery sends a request to the server with `callback=someFunctionName` in the URL. In this case the server response should be

```
someFunctionName(HERE THE DATA)
```

Also, `complete` callback gets as first argument always the `jqXHR` object, not the returned data, because `complete` is called by jQuery in both - request success and error - scenarios. Better use `success` callback for fetching the data and `error` for handling errors or even the Promise interface (`.done()` and `.fail()` methods).

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://abcd.com/cccbsapp/test.php",
    // Tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
    dataType: "jsonp"           
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function () {
    console.log("An error occured");
});
```

As an alternative way to using `JSONP`, you could just stick to normal JSON requests. To make Cross-Origin requests work, the server needs to include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response, e.g.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

(instead of the * you can list domains that are allowed to query this API)

Comment: I have added header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); and it works now. But I want to know that I have already added it inside .htaccess Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*", but it was not working. Can you please help me in understanding PHP access vs .htaccess Access.

Comment: @raju Just guessing, but If PHP on your server runs through fastcgi, maybe the issue is related to this: stackoverflow.com/a/38159002/80720