# Error when parsing data from json "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Tags: json, python-3.x, jsonparser

This is my code below:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import requests

url = 'https://production-us-adidasgroup.demandware.net/s/adidas-US/dw/shop/v15_6/products/(CQ1862)?client_id=392f521c-cf82-4c24-8ee4-97b4bfe926c5&expand=availability,variations,prices&callback=jQuery311046436681352330944_1508679685699&_=1508679685720.json'

s = requests.session()

res = s.get(url)
json_dict = res.json()

qty = json_dict['inventory']['ats']

print(qty)
```

I am trying to parse the 'ats' from the url, but keep running into error:

> simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1
>   (char 0)

I think it's because in the URL the first line doesn't have value. Is there any way to skip this? I know I'm not using some of the modules I have imported.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are receiving a [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839966/can-anyone-explain-what-jsonp-is-in-layman-terms) response which includes a function name. If you `curl` that URL you'll see the response starts with `/**/jQuery311046436681352330944_1508679685699({`. This is the same value you can see in the URL: `callback=jQuery311046436681352330944_1508679685699`

To get rid of this, drop the `callback` parameter from the URL. Use `https://production-us-adidasgroup.demandware.net/s/adidas-US/dw/shop/v15_6/products/(CQ1862)?client_id=392f521c-cf82-4c24-8ee4-97b4bfe926c5&expand=availability,variations,prices&_=1508679685720.json` instead.

Comment: i still get the same jsonDecodeError, can you run it?

Comment: Odd… I can get it with `curl`, but not using `requests` library