# PHP: JSON_DECODE is not working for the following data

Tags: php, jsondecoder

I'm trying to decode this json data by below code, but it's not working.

```
$data = 'VA_OnQueryData({"name":"John","id":"354902332592"});';
return json_decode($data);
```

Comment: That is not JSON

Comment: I'm getting this data from API, so i need to decode it.

Comment: `{"name":"John","id":"354902332592"}` is JSON, the outside looks like a JS call.

Comment: @SilaKhatun There's a good chance this API offers a proper JSON format.  Use that instead.

Comment: there is no way to offer json :(
https://api.vinaudit.com/query.php?key=VA_MAIN&callback=VA_OnQueryData&vin=1C6RR6LT3HS847897

Comment: It looks more like a JSONP response

Comment: @SilaKhatun, [yes there is](https://api.vinaudit.com/query.php?key=VA_MAIN&callback=&vin=1C6RR6LT3HS847897).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Get rid of the `callback` parameter in your URL.  Instead of this:

https://api.vinaudit.com/query.php?key=VA_MAIN&callback=VA_OnQueryData&vin=1C6RR6LT3HS847897

Use this:

https://api.vinaudit.com/query.php?key=VA_MAIN&vin=1C6RR6LT3HS847897

Then, you'll get real useful JSON.

The method you were using was [JSON-P](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3839966/362536), and used to be used to get around cross-domain issues by sending up executable JavaScript.  This method is no longer required client-side thanks to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), and was never required server-side.

Also, go back to whomever makes this API and tell them they're using the wrong `Content-Type` response header.  They're sending `text/html`... it should be `application/json`.  (Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/477819/362536)

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it.

Comment: @SilaKhatun If you found this answer useful, you can accept it as the answer to your problem by clicking the check mark next to it.  Then, it will bounce to the top for future readers.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hi what you are trying to json_decode is not valid json.

If you have to work with it this way, you will need to clean it first as follows:

```
$data = 'VA_OnQueryData({"vin":"1C6RR6LT3HS847897","id":"697015470432","attributes":{"VIN":"1C6RR6LT3HS847897","Year":"2017","Make":"Ram","Model":"1500","Trim":"Lone Star","Made In":"United States","Style":"Crew Cab Pickup (4-Door)","Engine":"5.7L V8 OHV 16V"},"success":true,"error":""});';

preg_match('/{.*}/', $data, $cleaned);

return json_decode($cleaned[0]);
```

The output of this is:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [vin] => 1C6RR6LT3HS847897
    [id] => 697015470432
    [attributes] => stdClass Object
        (
            [VIN] => 1C6RR6LT3HS847897
            [Year] => 2017
            [Make] => Ram
            [Model] => 1500
            [Trim] => Lone Star
            [Made In] => United States
            [Style] => Crew Cab Pickup (4-Door)
            [Engine] => 5.7L V8 OHV 16V
        )

    [success] => 1
    [error] => 
)
```

Comment: Good fallback if he couldn't tell the API to reduce that extra data.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because it is not a json. Try this instead:

```
$data = '{"name":"John","id":"354902332592"}';
return json_decode($data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i have to decode this data
$data = 'VA_OnQueryData({"name":"John","id":"354902332592"});';
cause i'm getting in this format from API.