# Getting CORS error even when using cors library

Tags: javascript, express, http-status-code-503, render.com

I'm getting a cors error when trying to host my project on render using expressjs and react. everything works fine when using local host, but changing the urls to match the site throws this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://book-listing-app-api.onrender.com/login' from origin 'https://book-listing-app.onrender.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I've tried manually adding the header in the request as well as using fetch instead of axios incase of a default configuration issue, but I still get some type of blocked by cors error.

```js
function Login() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

  async function loginUser(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/login`,
        {
          username: username,
          password: password,
        },
        {
          withCredentials: true,
          // headers: {
          //   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://book-listing-app.onrender.com",
          // },
        }
      );
      // const response = await fetch(
      //   `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/login`,
      //   {
      //     method: "POST",
      //     headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
      //     body: JSON.stringify({
      //       username: username,
      //       password: password,
      //     }),
      //     credentials: 'include'
      //   }
      // );
      if (response.status === 200) {
        setRedirect(true);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.response.status === 401) {
        alert("Invalid username or password");
      }
    }
  }
```

I've also tried adding additional options in the cors configuration on the backend and manually setting the header in the '/login' method using res.set().. both of which still display a blocked by cors error.

```js
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: 'https://book-listing-app.onrender.com',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
    allowedHeaders: ['content-type', 'Authorization', 'token'],
  }),
);
// app.options('/login', cors());
```

```js
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    console.log(username, password);

    if (!username || !password) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ error: 'Username and password are required' });
    }

    const q = 'SELECT * FROM book_store.users WHERE username = ?';

    db.query(q, [username], (err, data) => {
      console.log('Query Error:', err);
      console.log('Query Result:', data);
      if (err) {
        console.log(data);
      }

      if (data.length === 1) {
        const { id, username, password: storedPass } = data[0];
        console.log('Entered password:', password);
        console.log('Stored hashed password:', storedPass);
        const passMatch = bcrypt.compareSync(password, storedPass);
        if (passMatch) {
          jwt.sign(
            {
              id,
              username,
            },
            secret,
            {
              expiresIn: '1h',
            },
            (err, token) => {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
              } else {
                // res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://book-listing-app.onrender.com');
                res.cookie('token', token).json({ id, username });
              }
            },
          );
        }
      } else {
        res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid username or password' });
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
  }
});
```

Additionally, I've reached out to render and they said their site in no way affects cors so its definitely a problem with the code. I've tried hosting it on azure to confirm this and got the same cors error.

Comment: Everything looks right so long as the `app.use(cors(...))` is **before** `app.post('/login', ...)`. If that is the case, have you verified that you've deployed the latest version of your Express app?

Comment: I wasn't but I updated everything to it's latest version and still the same error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Is `app.use(cors())` registered first?

Comment: Yes, it's at the top before any end points.

Comment: This is simply **not reproducible**. Again, I feel you haven't deployed your changes. Add some extra logging and monitor your server logs to ensure it is running what you expect. Even something as simple as `console.log('Adding CORS support for https://book-listing-app.onrender.com')` just after `app.use(cors(...))`. If that doesn't show up when you next deploy / start your app on Render.com, then there's your answer

Comment: What are the response headers?

Comment: So I have render linked to my repository and it auto re-deploys when I push any change. I console logged your suggestion and it shows up on the server logs upon re-deployment. You're welcome visit the site and try logging in with user: 'test', pass: 'test' to see the error along with viewing the code on my github 
https://github.com/NimbusManski/book-listing-app
It's a pretty small project if you have time to take a look.

Comment: Uh, your service isn't actually working. Did you not notice the [503 Service Unavailable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503) response status?

Comment: Where do you see this? The only response status I see is 502 bad gateway for login

Comment: In the network dev-tools panel. Sometimes it's a 502, others a 503. In either case, it means your backend service is unreachable. This is **not a CORS issue**

Comment: Plenty of ideas in [this thread](https://community.render.com/t/web-service-returning-http-1-1-502-bad-gateway/117/5)

Comment: Interesting.. I can confirm the back end is live via the "backend running" json message  I set for when I visit the server url. The front end is obviously also working, and I'm confident I've set the right url's in the code itself. Am I missing something? I can't think of why the backend wouldn't be working.

Comment: I'll look this thread over. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The CORS header needs to be in the response, not the request. The goal of CORS is for the server to decide which origin domains have access to server side data (for CORS compliant browsers).

When https://book-listing-app-api.onrender.com/login receives a request from origin https://book-listing-app.onrender.com, CORS applies.

The server response needs to include an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://book-listing-app.onrender.com` header authorizing cross origin requests from the domain *book-listing-app.onrender.com*.

Other `Access-Control-*` headers may be needed depending on the goal of the cross origin request.

`Access-Control-Allow-Methods: <HTTP METHOD>` limits the CORS request to a specific HTTP Method. `GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD` are the default methods.

`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: <boolean>` controls whether cookies are honored or not.

Browsers are increasingly more strict about CORS rules. The exact *protocol://domain:port* should be returned in the CORS `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header from https://book-listing-app-api.onrender.com/login for the most comprehensive security.

- [How do CORS and Access-Control-Allow-Headers work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630231/how-do-cors-and-access-control-allow-headers-work)
- [CORS not working on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136140/cors-not-working-on-chrome)
- [CORS not working on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136140/cors-not-working-on-chrome)
- [Why does my http://localhost CORS origin not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/why-does-my-http-localhost-cors-origin-not-work)
- [Allow cors on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59725454/allow-cors-on-localhost)

Comment: Unless something has changed recently, the only restriction on `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is that it cannot be used with `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`

Comment: @Phil there are also `localhost` restrictions, depending on the browser, which can make development more involved.

Comment: The backend code is posted as well. The commented out res.set method is the code I tried but it also gave me a cors error. The reason I tried setting the header from the front end is that I've tried everything from the backend with no luck.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Test CORS in a compliant browser yourself. It isn't difficult to test and the error message tells developers the reason exactly. `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://book-listing-app-api.onrender.com/login' from origin 'https://book-listing-app.onrender.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` Set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response, just like the message says to do.

Comment: OP is already using the [cors middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) which does exactly that

Comment: @Phil OP provided the CORS error from the browser that says the request is blocked because of missing CORS headers so OP needs to post actual HTTP headers to prove cors middleware is working otherwise don't make assumptions.