# SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 1 with JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, api, npm-request

I am trying to use openweathermap.org weather api, I am getting the data but having trouble parsing it.

Here's my code:

```
request("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=30.4831&lon=76.595&appid=7beb6de85d3f3a28dabda1015684562f&units=metric&callback=test", function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(typeof body);
    }
});
```

`console.log(typeof body);` returns string so I just can't figure out what 's the problem.

Comment: That API is a JSONP API, and it does not respond with parseable JSON. Instead, the response takes the form of a JavaScript function call. That's what the "callback" parameter is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for this - the URL is [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839966/can-anyone-explain-what-jsonp-is-in-layman-terms) so it expects a function called test and no need to parse

```html
<script>
const test = data => console.log(data);
</script>
<script src="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=30.4831&lon=76.595&appid=7beb6de85d3f3a28dabda1015684562f&units=metric&callback=test"></script>
```

Alternatively remove the callback - here using fetch:

```js
fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=30.4831&lon=76.595&appid=7beb6de85d3f3a28dabda1015684562f&units=metric")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Or Axios

```js
axios.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=30.4831&lon=76.595&appid=7beb6de85d3f3a28dabda1015684562f&units=metric')
  .then(response => console.log(response.data));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Just set object for the first argument with url and json property. set `json:true`. Setting to true will handle the parsing for you :)

```
const request = require('request');
const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=30.4831&lon=76.595&appid=7beb6de85d3f3a28dabda1015684562f&units=metric";

request({ url: url, json: true }, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
  }
});
```

As @mplungjan pointed out. That's a [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-and-why-was-it-created) url.

Comment: Ah, I did not know how to do this using `request`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `&callback=test` at the end of your URL then you don't have to deal with JSONP and you can work with it like normal.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an API which has a callback function return as response. It is not JSON but JSONP (JSON with Padding).
Your code will work just fine if you remove the callback parameter from URL.

```
request("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=30.4831&lon=76.595&appid=7beb6de85d3f3a28dabda1015684562f&units=metric", function(error, response, body) {
       if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          console.log(response);
       }
   });
```

For further reading about JSONP, You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-and-why-was-it-created).