# Not a Legal JSONP API -- How to get data without CALLBACK parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, jsonp

## Angular 1.6 - JSONP throws EXCEPTION despite Response with status: 200 Ok for URL

Im trying to grab some data from a JSONP endpoint. It looks like the data is being returned in the response but Angular nonetheless throws an error.

```
var url = "https://careers.icims.com/jobs-api/"

var trustedUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);

$http.jsonp(trustedUrl, {jsonpCallbackParam: 'jobs'}).then(function(res){

    console.log(res); // this is never executed :.(

});
```

I am getting the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jobs is not defined
    at jobs-api?jobs=angular.callbacks._0:1`
where `jobs` refers to my JSONP prefix

Yet the response returns the JSONP script:
[image]

Why is this exception being thrown and how can it be cleared? I am on Angular 1.6.0

Comment: you don't have a function called `jobs` - that API always returns JSONP that calls a function called `jobs`

Comment: wouldnt `jobs` be implicitly defined within the scope of `then()`? Nonetheless, in what scope would I define `jobs`. I tried simply defining `function jobs(){}` above the jsonp call but no luck

Comment: jobs needs to be global

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Not a Legal JSONP API

The API at that URL is not a [legal JSONP API.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)

It can be gotten with a dangerous service:

```
app.service("dangerousAPI", function($q) {
  this.get = get;
  
  function get(funcName, url) {
    var dataDefer = $q.defer();
  
    window[funcName] = function(x) {
      dataDefer.resolve(x);
    }

    var tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.src = url;

    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag);
    
    return dataDefer.promise;
  }
})
```

Use at your own risk.

## [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/1nXa7N362KXxVf89ctIN?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.service("dangerousAPI", function($q) {
  this.get = get;
  
  function get(funcName, url) {
    var dataDefer = $q.defer();
  
    window[funcName] = function(x) {
      dataDefer.resolve(x);
    }

    var tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.src = url;

    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag);
    
    return dataDefer.promise;
  }
})

.run(function($rootScope, dangerousAPI) {
    var url = "https://careers.icims.com/jobs-api/";
    dangerousAPI.get('jobs',url).then(function(data) {
      $rootScope.data = data;
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <h1>Dangerous API DEMO</h1>
    <pre>{{data | json}}</pre>
  </body>
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you! If you would indulge me, what about this API is not legal and dangerous?

Comment: Standard JSONP accepts a callback parameter to define the name of the padding function. This example code by-passes the browser [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) and AngularJS security measures for URL sanitation and other mechanisms that make JSONP calls safer. For more information, see [*Is JSONP safe to use?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613962/is-jsonp-safe-to-use).

Comment: See also [AngularJS $http Service - Security Consideration](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#security-considerations).

Comment: See also [AngularJS Developer Guide - Security](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/security). And [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to V1.6 $http JSONP](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrate1.5to1.6-ng-services-$http).