# Angularjs $http get method for JSONP data without CALLBACK parameter

Tags: php, angularjs, json, jsonp, http-method

I have problem by printing in the table, some JSON that is on the server.
This is my JSON

```
process([
{
    "name": "A",
    "value": "41"
},
{
    "name": "B",
    "value": "71"
},
{
    "name": "C",
    "value": "20"
}],"2017.07.11 15:48:33");
```

My controller:

```
myApp.controller('liveTable', function ($scope, $http) {

$http.get('http://something.com/get.php?jsonp=2017')
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.myData= response.data;
        console.log(response.data);
    });
```

And this is my HTML

```
 <div class="liveTable" ng-controller="liveTable">
             <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in myData.process">
                    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.value}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
```

Have any idea where I'm wrong? tnx

Comment: Do you see data in console.?

Comment: that doesnt seem like valid json

Comment: yes I see data in console

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
app.service("dangerousAPI", function($q) {
  this.get = get;

  function get(funcName, url) {
    var dataDefer = $q.defer();

    window[funcName] = function(x) {
      dataDefer.resolve(x);
    }

    var tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.src = url;

    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag);

    return dataDefer.promise;
  }
})
```

```
dangerousAPI.get('process',url).then(function(data) {
     $scope.myData= data;
     console.log(data);
})
```

For more information, see [Not a Legal JSONP API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44752928/5535245)

---

> when I put `{{myData}}`, I have complet jsonp,

I am glad you were able to get the data with this answer. It shows that the server is not returning legal JSON. The server should be fixed to return either legal JSON or legal [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

To make the server respond with a valid [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) array, wrap the JSON in brackets () and prepend the callback:

```
echo $_GET['callback']."([{'fullname' : 'Jeff Hansen'}])";
Using json_encode() will convert a native PHP array into JSON:

$array = array(
    'fullname' => 'Jeff Hansen',
    'address' => 'somewhere no.3'
);
echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($array).")";
```

For more information, see [Simple PHP and JSONP example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6809286/5535245)

Comment: when I put {{myData}}, I have complet jsonp, I would like print element by element, any idea?

Comment: I am glad you were able to get the data with this answer. It shows that the server is not returning legal JSON. The server should be fixed to return either legal JSON or legal [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with your json data.

i can see by changing you json data. you can have a look on it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myapp">
 <div class="liveTable" ng-controller="myctrl">
             <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in process">
                    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.value}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
angular.module("myapp",[]).controller("myctrl", function($scope){
  $scope.process = ([
{
    "name": "A",
    "value": "41"
},
{
    "name": "B",
    "value": "71"
},
{
    "name": "C",
    "value": "20"
}]);
 

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```